# Printf only printing once after fork in two-line program

Tags: c, printf, fork

I have a two-line program to print the id of the processes after the fork. I expect some number such as `66015` for the parent process, and `0` for the child process.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
  pid_t id = fork();
  printf("id: %i\n", id);
}
```

However the program only prints

```
id: 66015
```

And does not include the line

```
id: 0
```

Could someone explain what's going on? I'm relatively new to `C` and `fork`.

I'm on OSX 10.11, and `gcc --version` prints

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.38)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Comment: What system are you compiling for?  Your code works as expected on OS/X

Comment: I'm on OSX 10.11. Will put more details in question.

Comment: I am running 10.11.6 with a slightly older version of LLVM (7.0.0) and your code behaves as expected.

Comment: Do you run the program in the terminal or redirect its output or somehow run it inside an IDE?

Comment: @chqrlie that was it...I was running it in emacs `eshell`, which in hindsight was dumb.

Comment: Use qemacs instead ;-) it has a better shell mode.

Comment: @self I wouldn't say it was nonsensical. The problem was real, but just an issue with environment...not code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program should indeed output both lines in any given order.  Running it in the terminal would do that.  Running it in some quirky environment such as emacs' eshell window may have surprising side effects such as what you experienced.

Comment: I think some IDE provides their own libraries for debugging purposes, much like valgrind provides their own except it isn't an IDE. Their provided library may not have a full blown fork().

Comment: @alvits: emacs does not provide a library, it runs the program compiled by clang but the way it captures the output works differently from what happens in the terminal window. It should be considered a bug.

Comment: You are absolutely right. While emacs doesn't provide its own set of development libraries, the OP mentioned `eshell` which I believe is built for emacs. This `eshell` is what I was thinking that might contain libraries as it provides most interface that a regular shell does. I have not used `eshell`, hence _I believe_.

Comment: Several emacs packages implement a shell buffer: `eshell` is a builtin shell that does not rely on the unix shell, bash or other. It has its own command line parser and implements I/O redirection in a way that seems incorrect or incomplete. The emacs `shell` command uses virtual ttys and runs the unix shell in manner more compatible with the unix terminals, except it does not implement escape sequences, hence it behaves as a *dumb* terminal.  `qemacs` also uses virtual ttys and implements VT100 escape sequences in its terminal emulation: you can even run emacs inside the qemacs process window.